# Why is RobotState not the same in different nodes?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, move-group-interface, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attaching a collision object to my robot. The object is displayed fine and reported correctly as the cause of a collision if I move it into a wall in Rviz. I also added some debug messages that make it clear that the RobotState in the move_group node knows about this object.

However, I have two other nodes running, which have a move_group_interface and a MoveGroupCommander in C++/Python respectively, and neither of their RobotStates seem to be aware of the attached object. They are both running when the AttachedCollisionObject is published, but their state does not change.

I check with this code in the C++ node:

```
robot_state::RobotState state(*group_interface.getCurrentState());
std::vector<const robot_state::AttachedBody*> ab;
state.getAttachedBodies(ab);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Current state has " << ab.size() << " attached bodies.");
```

But the result stays 0, even though it should say 1 after attaching the object (a similar debug message does report the correct number in the move_group node).

Normally it would not be a problem since the collisions are checked in the move_group node, but I need these attached objects to construct my planning goal. What am I missing? How can I update the RobotState? Thanks in advance.

I build MoveIt from source on the kinetic-devel branch and use ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

edit: I am using the PlanningSceneInterface to attach the collision object and not publishing a message manually, if that makes a difference.

edit2: I may have found the reason for this behavior in the description of the PlanningSceneInterface applyAttachedCollisionObject function:

```
Other PlanningSceneMonitors will NOT receive the update unless they subscribe to move_group's monitored scene
```

I'm not sure how to do that or why that wouldn't be the default behavior of the move_group_interface, but any pointers are welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302330/why-is-robotstate-not-the-same-in-different-nodes?/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I can't say I have a plain answer to your problem because it depends on your specific node setup.

Your second edit is right in that the `PlanningSceneInterface.apply*` functions only affect the `move_group` node.
This is because the functions use the ros service provided by the `move_group` node.
If you instantiate your own `PlanningSceneMonitor` in a different node, you have to connect it to `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` to receive the updates. But these are throttled (2 Hz by default I think) and of course updates there are asynchronous.

Historically the only way to update the scene was asynchronously via the add* functions (published messages).
There all nodes/monitors got the updates.... or not because messages where dropped/not connected/...

The proper way to go for you might be to get a fresh planning scene from the `move_group` node right when you need it.
You can use the GetPlanningScene service for that, or better, you utilize the `PlanningSceneInterface` and just add a method that exposes the full possibilities of the service there.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-04**:
Thanks for the answer. I already made it a MoveGroupCapability. Is there a reason that `move_group_interface` does not include AttachedBody objects or even the whole scene? I see that it instantiates a `CurrentStateMonitor`, but that only tracks TF and JointStates.